# How to print comma “,” in the middle of sentenced when necessary, Part 2, Perl

Tags: perl

I need to print comma "," when the list more than one, and if more than one, the last list I don't want to print comma. I know I can use Join to to do this but I can't loop multidimensional hash with comma if there is another data to add in.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::Autotie 'Tie::IxHash';

tie my %try, 'Tie::IxHash';
$try{STRONG}{ALLIES}='A';
$try{AGILE}{BOBBY}='B';
$try{AGILE}{HOBBY}='B';
$try{SMART}{CAKRA}='C';
$try{SMART}{PHONE}='C';
$try{SMART}{PEOPLE}='C';

foreach my $temp_0 (keys %try)
{
    print "\n//$temp_0\n\n";
    foreach my $temp_1 (keys %{$try{$temp_0}})
    {
        print "$temp_1, // $try{$temp_0}{$temp_1}\n";
     }
 }
```

Current Output:

```
//STRONG

ALLIES, // A

//AGILE

BOBBY, // B
HOBBY, // B

//SMART

CAKRA, // C
PHONE, // C
PEOPLE, // C
```

Expected Output:

```
//STRONG

ALLIES // A

//AGILE

BOBBY, // B
HOBBY // B

//SMART

CAKRA, // C
PHONE, // C
PEOPLE // C
```

Comment: You should use a different data structure: Walk through your original data structure, and build a hash of arrays from that so you can then use `join( ',', @items )` to output the stuff with commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch your inner loop to be a C-style for loop to go over the keys and don't do the last one, then treat it separately afterwards. You will need a list of the inner keys in an array to do that. It also makes sense to sort them so you can reproduce the same result all the time.

```
foreach my $temp_0 (sort keys %try)
{
    # heading
    print "\n//$temp_0\n\n";

    # all but the last entry
    my @keys = sort keys %{$try{$temp_0}};
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $#keys; $i++) {
        print "$keys[$i], // $try{$temp_0}{$keys[$i]}\n";
    }

    # the last entry
    print "$keys[-1] // $try{$temp_0}{$keys[-1]}\n";
 }
```

Comment: ... alternatively, `pop` the last element, output the rest with comma, and then output the last element without a comma

Comment: You specifically mention switching to a C-style loop as if that's a crucial detail, but what's the benefit of your C-style loop over `for my $i (0 .. $#keys-1) {...}`?

Comment: @DaveSherohman there is none. I mostly chose this because for someone who's not intimately familiar with what's _Perlish_ and what isn't, I assumed it easier to understand. It makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it is as simple as putting a comma between a list of items with nothing else in between, you can use a `join` with `','` as @Corion mentioned.  Since you have other stuff (comments) in between them, here's a simple change that works:

```
foreach my $temp_0 (keys %try)
{
    print "\n//$temp_0\n\n";
    my @keys = keys %{$try{$temp_0}};
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#keys; $i++) {
        my $com = ($i < $#keys) ? ',' : '';
        print "$keys[$i]$com // $try{$temp_0}{$keys[$i]}\n";
     }
}
```